# How to extract Zip inside Zip with all unique file Id?

Tags: c#, winforms, zip

I am using Windows Application. My problem is I want to display Files Parentid and it's unique Id in List with Name of Files. I have tried below code. It's working fine with ParentId, But when It comes to pkUniqueId it also take parent Id due to below commented line. It's calling same method and replace pkUniqueId with previous value. My Zip file structure is

1) Test.Zip

```
  1.1) Test1.Zip
      1.1.1) SampleDoc1.doc
      1.1.2) SampleDoc2.doc
  1.2) SampleText1.txt
  1.3) SampleText2.txt
```

Above structure generating Parent Id for it's child properly. But UniqueId for Last two documents are replicated.

If my file Structure will be

1) Test.Zip

```
  1.1) SampleText1.txt
  1.2) SampleText2.txt
  1.3) Test1.zip
      1.3.1) SampleDoc1.doc
      1.3.2) SampleDoc2.doc
```

then it's working as expected.

```
public static List<ZipExtracFile> ZipFile(string filePath, string initialDirectory, int pkUniqueId)
{
    int extractFileParentId = pkUniqueId;


    List<ZipExtracFile> extractFileList = new List<ZipExtracFile>();

    using (ZipArchive archive = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            pkUniqueId = pkUniqueId + 1;
            extractFileList.Add(new ZipExtracFile { pkUniqueId = pkUniqueId, fileName = entry.Name, parentId = extractFileParentId });

            if (Path.GetExtension(entry.FullName).ToLower() == ".zip")
            {
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(initialDirectory, entry.FullName);

                extractFileList.AddRange(ZipFile(fullPath, initialDirectory, pkUniqueId)); // Due to this Line
            }

        }
    }
    return extractFileList;
}
```

Any suggestion? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Srusti,

I believe that due to your method being implemented as a **recursive** method, it is guaranteed that items on the same depth level of recursion will not receive the same `pkUniqueId` values, but items in a deeper recursion level can receive **duplicate** `pkUniqueId` values.

That happens because methods deeper in the recursive calls will increase the `pkUniqueId` values, but when they finish their executions, the increased `pkUniqueId` values will be lost, and methods in the shallower recursion levels will never now that `pkUniqueId` has increased. Please, try using a debugger to execute your application step-by-step and verify how the id generation causes loss in your specific case.

I'd suggest you to try implementing that method using a non-recursive approach. Another way to solve this is to pass the `pkUniqueId` parameter of your method per-reference, to guarantee that its changes in deeper recursion levels will be reflected in shallower recursion levels.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It's happened due to recursive. Can you please provide code for your suggested solution?

Comment: I believe that by simply replacing your declaration `int pkUniqueId` by `ref int pkUniqueId` will solve the problem. Also, don't forget to pass `ref pkUniqueId` when calling `extractFileList.AddRange(...)`. I have no ways to test this right now, but please message back if that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Okay Let me try

Comment: Thank you very much. It's Working as expected.